# Laravel 4 Authentication

Tags: php, authentication, laravel, laravel-4

I'm having trouble getting the Authentication to work with laravel 4. This is my whole sign in function when a user enters their email and password into the form.

```
public function getSignin() {
    $return_arr = array();

    $email = Input::get('email');
    $password = Input::get('password');

    $validation = Validator::make(
                    array(
                'Email' => $email,
                'Password' => $password
                    ), array(
                'Email' => 'required|Email',
                'Password' => 'required'
                    )
    );

    if ($validation->passes()) {
        $pass = base64_encode($password);

        $details = array ('email' => $email, 'password' => $pass);

        if (Auth::attempt($details)) {
            $return_arr['frm_check'] = 'success';
            $return_arr['msg'] = 'logged in';
        } else {
            $return_arr['frm_check'] = 'error';
            $return_arr['msg'] = 'log in failed';
        }
    } else {
        $errors = $validation->messages();
        $return_arr['frm_check'] = 'error';
        $return_arr['msg'] = $errors->first();
    }

    echo json_encode($return_arr);
    $this->layout = null;
    return;
}
```

Even though the email and password are in the same row in the database, it still returns log in failed, was wondering if anyone could shed some light on to this situation?

If I've missed off any other crucial details let me know and I'll post them right away. Thanks in advance.

Comment: why are you doing this before `Auth::attempt()`?  `$pass = base64_encode($password);` shouldn't be necessary!

Comment: Because when they register for an account it generates a password, sends the password to their email, it converts the password to base64 and puts in the db as a base64 string... when they log in, the plain text they enter in the password box gets converted to base64 so it can check against the base64 value in the db

Comment: OK, laravel expects the password to be BCrypted.. so instead of base_64'ing the password when they create it, use `Hash::make($password)` before storing it in the DB.  Then you can use `Auth::attempt()` with the plain-text password entered by your user.

Comment: That's fixed it, thank you very much. If you put it in a proper answer I'll accept it and vote up for you

Comment: cheers!  Added below :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your comments...

When you're creating your $user, use [`Hash::make($password)`](http://laravel.com/docs/security#storing-passwords) to hash the password using BCrypt, before saving it in your db.

Then, when the user's logging in just use [`Auth::attempt($credentials)`](http://laravel.com/docs/security#authenticating-users) as you are, but don't use base_64 to encrypt it, the Auth method does it all for you!

Much more on the excellent Laravel docs: http://laravel.com/docs/security

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have base64 encoded your password on save(), remove this line from your code:

```
$pass = base64_encode($password);
```

And edit this one to:

```
$details = array ('email' => $email, 'password' => $password);
```

`Auth::attempt()` will hash it for you, using something safer than base64.

EDIT:

To correctly save your passwords you have to do something like this:

```
$user = new User;
$user->email = 'me@me.com';
$user->password = Hash::make('mySuperSecretPassword');
$user->save();
```

Then you can user attempt just passing it unhashed.

Comment: I have used base64_encode on the password on save(), any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a tutorial I wrote; which might help!

https://medium.com/on-coding/e8d93c9ce0e2